# SQL Server round()

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I want to round value of one select

For example:

```
select width from Home
```

The result of `width` is "3.999999999999999"

I want to be "3.99" or "3.9"

Comment: If you want 3.99 or 3.9, then you do not want `round()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only two decimal values you can multiply by 100, floor the result and divide by 100 (This is necessary because floor works only flooring a number to an integer):

```
select floor(width * 100) / 100 from Home
```

Here are the steps

```
3.99999999 * 100 = 399.999999    --- Multiply by 100
floor(399.999999) = 399          --- floor 
399 / 100 = 3.99                 --- Divide by 100
```

---

It is also possible using a different form of [round function with a third parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(SQL.90).aspx).

When the third parameter is different from 0 the result is truncated instead of rounded

> **Syntax**
>
> `ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> `numeric_expression` Is an expression of the exact numeric or
>   approximate numeric data type category, except for the bit data type.
>
> `length` Is the precision to which numeric_expression is to be rounded.
>   length must be an expression of type tinyint, smallint, or int. When
>   length is a positive number, numeric_expression is rounded to the
>   number of decimal positions specified by length. When length is a
>   negative number, numeric_expression is rounded on the left side of the
>   decimal point, as specified by length.
>
> `function` Is the type of
>   operation to perform. function must be tinyint, smallint, or int. When
>   function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression
>   is rounded. **When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression**
>   **is truncated.**

Here is the select using this version of `round`:

```
 select round(width, 2, 1) from Home
```

Comment: same answer, better presentation :)

Answer (score 4):

`ROUND(width, 1 or 2, 1)` should work best for you. Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(13,2), ROUND(width, 2, 1))
FROM Home
```

will return 3.99, and

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(13,1), ROUND(width, 1, 1))
FROM Home
```

will return 3.9

Comment: You can change it according to your schema. Check the type of your column "width". If it is Numeric(x, y) then your code should work for NUMERIC(x,1 or 2). I assumed it to be NUMERIC(13,y).

Answer (score 3):

If you want a value of 3.99 or 3.9, then you do not want `round()`.  You want `floor()`.  However, that works on integers, but not decimals.

The naive method of `cast(width as decimal(10,2))` will return `4.00`, as will `round(width, 2)`.  One method is to subtract a small amount.  So:

```
select cast(width - 0.005 as decimal(10, 2))
```

should give you "3.99".

Comment: it's just a sample, how should I do it for range of data ?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple, if you want the result 3.9 then

```
select round(width,1) from Home
```

If you need the result 3.99 then use..

```
select round(width,2) from Home
```